# Stop execution of code in x minutes

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have an application, where commands is send in x minutes intervals to a serial port. The code:

```
int i = 0;

do
{
      // Send temperature
      com.SendComMessage(Temperature[i], Command[i]);

       // Start timer
       System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer();
       t.Elapsed += new TimerElapsedEventHandler();
       t.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(Time[i]);
       t.AutoReset = false;
       t.Enabled = true;

        // Tell CarbageCollector not to destroy the timer
        GC.KeepAlive(t);

        i++;

} while (i <= count);
```

I want to stop executing the loop until the time have elapsed.

I have considered using threads, like this:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(Time[i])*60);
```

But I may wont to update the GUI while the code is sleeping, since the serial port receives reponses from the device.

How can I achive this?

Comment: Is the Timer to see if you haven't gotten a response back in X seconds?...or are you just wanting a delay between the commands you send?

Comment: @Idle_Mind Just a delay between the commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then Steven Rands already gave you a good answer using async/await with Task.Delay():

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        // Send temperature
        com.SendComMessage(Temperature[i], Command[i]);
        await Task.Delay(1000); // wait one second before continuing
        i++;
    } while (i <= count);
}
```

Note the method has been marked with `async`, and we are `await`ing the `Task.Delay()` call.  This will result in a responsive GUI that can still receive events while waiting one second before moving on to the next iteration of the loop.

If you need to have a time out period combined with a success/failure type scenario, then consider something like this instead:

```
    private System.Threading.ManualResetEvent MRE = new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false);

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;

        bool result = false;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++ )
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Message " + i.ToString() + " Sent");

            MRE.Reset();
            await Task.Run(delegate()
            {
                result = MRE.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); // wait up to ten seconds for MRE to be set
            });

            if (result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Success!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Timeout Fail");
            }
        }

        button1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // simulated receipt of something
        Console.WriteLine("...bloop...");
        MRE.Set(); // tell the main loop it's okay to continue
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the GUI then you need to run the serial port comms code in a different thread to the UI.

Use either the Task Parallel Library (ie. `Task` objects, `async` and `await`) or something like `BackgroundWorker` to shift the comms code to a background thread.

Inside your background thread you will effectively have a loop that sends a command to the COM port then decodes the response. Inside that loop you can use `Thread.Sleep(...)` or `await Task.Delay(...)` to "pause" between requests.